# AMQP or MQTT which can I choose?

Tags: android, amqp, mqtt

I want to build a backend application to push messages from server to android devices.And I found there two protocols are suit the situation.I'd like to use RabbitMQ or mosquitto server for each of them(If there is other good choices please tell me too :-) ).Considering about poor network situation,battery using and server performance.Which solution is suit for me ?

I also found C2DM service.But it has two problem in my situation.Firstly it only supported Android 2.2 and later versions.Secondly the service in China is not always stable.So that is why I want to build my own push service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MQTT was explicitly built for devices with limited resources and is therefore very light on battery by comparison to other protocols. It is also designed for unreliable TCP networks. Worth taking a closer look.

Comment: We decided using MQTT finally

Comment: @Andy Piper Is RabbitMQ really bad for limited resource devices?

Comment: AMQP is really an enterprise messaging protocol so it is generally more "heavyweight" than MQTT, the nice thing about RabbitMQ is that you can now use the MQTT plugin so support that protocol too - so your server backend could use AMQP on RabbitMQ, and the client devices (mobiles, sensors etc) could use MQTT and interoperate.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud to Device](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/), but if has some drawbacks - like it's necessary for user to be logged in with Google account (well, you need to be logged in to use market, so it's not really a problem).

I will also suggest looking at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) tutorial.

Comment: I also found C2DM service.But it has two problem in my situation.Firstly it only supported Android 2.2 and later versions.Secondly the service in China is not always stable.So that is why I want to build my own push service.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate in the AMQP space is Apache Qpid. Rabbit is also good, but the products have some differing features you can consider.

Comment: Thanks for your advise,but I found its version is 0.14 at this time and I was wondring is it stable enough for using.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding... yes, Apache Qpid is stable - it's used in many demanding projects. Version 0.18 is nearing release now. The version numbers are 0-based because Qpid implements AMQP 0-10; will change to 1.x after support for the not-yet-officially-standardized OASIS AMQP 1.0 spec is added.